# Google App Engine - session not persisted to next servlet until I reload

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, session, servlets

I have two `servlets`: the first `loginServlet` authenticate the user through `Gmail` using `userService` object and persist credentials (`username` & `password`) in the session, after that it redirect to the second servlet `HomeServlet`, which is used to show the data saved in the `session`.

My issue is that the first time that data is saved in the `session`, it cant be retreived in the second one (It gaves me `null`). Until I goto the `firstServlet`.

The first Servlet is:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // initialize user authentification service
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    Boolean isConnected = (userService.getCurrentUser() != null);
    if (isConnected) {
      // save credentials in a session
      HttpSession session = req.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("username", userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname());
      session.setAttribute("email", userService.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
      session.setAttribute("isConnected", isConnected);

      // forward to login view
      resp.sendRedirect("/");
    }
    else
      // redirect to 'gmail' login page
      resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL("/"));

  }
}
```

And the second Servlet is:

```
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
  static {
    ObjectifyService.register(Message.class);
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
      List<Message> messages = ofy().load().type(Message.class).list();
      req.setAttribute("messages", messages);

      this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    Message message = new Message(req.getParameter("name"), req.getParameter("message"));
    ofy().save().entity(message).now();
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
  }
}
```

`'/'` is the path to the second servlet `GuestbookServlet`.

Comment: Without seeing some code it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (a noob one) was that the `if statement` in the `LoginServlet` was never accessed on first login, so nothing was written to the `session`.

I have to save the `session` in the second servlet if it doesnt exist yet.